# Receive data from PHP script with NSURLRequest

Tags: php, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have an app that sends data to a PHP script with the NSURLRequest and NSURLConnexion. What I want is to send a data like "Hello world" with post method, and I want display on my app "Hello world from myPHPScript.php !" but I have no experience on web service and specially n PHP.

Here is my objective-c code which sends the request :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL

                                URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/testNSURL/index.php"]

                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy

                                timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = @"myVariable=Hello world !";
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {

        receiveData = [NSMutableData data]; 

}
```

And this is my PHP code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["myVariable"])) {
    echo json_encode("Hello from index.php !");
}
else    echo json_encode('Request failed');
?>
```

My questions are :

- Is my PHP code correct?
- How can I catch the `echo json_encode("Hello from index.php !");` in my obj-c app?

Answer (score 0):

I personally am using [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) when posting things to a server. When you get info back from this method you can just do something like this to get the data/string value of all that has been echo'd on the server:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)aRequest {
    NSData *responseData = [aRequest responseData];
    NSString *responseString = [aRequest responseString];
}
```

Getting a string from Data information is done like so:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

Comment: I used it, but I had a lot of errors / warning with and without the ARC, this is why I used NSURLRequest / NSURLConnexion

Comment: Oh, never really had any problems with it at all.. Maybe i can help you with those errors?

Comment: I also added the way to get a string from nsdata :)

Comment: Well, I replaced all stuff that uses ASIHTTPRequest by the code above : /

Comment: So you want to get the strings that the php server outputs? If so you can use the second piece of code i added.

Comment: I will find for ASIHTTPRequest again, and update or make another topic about later, thank for try to help me ! :)

Comment: But i dont see any code of you starting the sending of the request you built. You should use `[theConnection start];` and get the data in the delegate method that gets called.